# Adding Custom Rows and Headers to ASP.NET GridView

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to work with a GridView to set up some custom rows and headers. Here is a small image of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

The box that has red around it is what im pulling through from C#, so that is already getting populated with what I need.

I have managed to create a header using C# but I really want to do this client side in the HTML,Javascript or jQuery.

The 'Rota' and Hours down the left are normal labels but a user can click the days across the top and the data in red needs to refresh.

**How can I create all of these custom rows in a GridView in ASP.NET**

EDIT

After saying a GridView is more server side control, I am happy to take answers about doing this server side.

Comment: The GridView is a server-side control and it would be better to use the GridView in this manner, rather than manipulating it client side afterwards. The GridView renders to an HTML table, so your question regarding client side manipulation is really... how to work with <table>, <tr>, <th> and so on using jQuery / JavaScript. Do you really need a GridView if you have decided to do things client side?

Comment: @MariusGeorge I just thought it may make things easier doing it client side. If its easier and better to use c# when doing this .. How could this be done?>

Comment: Have you decided already on WebForms vs ASP.NET MVC, etc? If you are dealing with a WebForms project here, then you should study some examples of GridView to learn how to use it. If you are doing MVC or plain HTML, you can build a simple table structure by hand. There is probably no "right" way to do it, just choose a path that you know best already for now.